# How can i access direct controller url in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url

Instead of default controller how can I call directly one controller? My requirement is: I need to call one controller separately for loading my view file. When I try the standard way of calling it I get redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the file in the config folder name route.php and replace

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';
```

to

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'your controller';
```

for more read this

http://w3code.in/2015/10/codeigniter-installation-beginner-guide/

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ricky.But i need something little different from the current one.
Currently i set as $route['default_controller'] = 'login';.
Is that possible to call one controller like this http://example.com/index.php/register/
when i call this i am getting the login page without style.

Comment: Make sure you first letter of your controller name wil be capital and the class name and controller name should be same

Comment: class Register extends CI_Controller { 
}
and the file name is Register.php

Comment: Can you please update your code in your question that will make for me easy to undestand.

Comment: <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*  
 *  @author : 
 *  26th Oct, 2015
 *  Registration Form
 *  
 */  
class Register extends CI_Controller {
 
 function __construct() {
        }

        public function index() {
              
  $this->load->view('backend/form');
        }

}
The above code i set for the controller Register.php
i called like wise http://example.com/index.php/register